# Cannot Copy Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working with SQL server 2012. I want to copy a database along with all the data. I just want to create a dev DB.

I know SQL Server 2012 has a Copy Database... wizard. But when I run that wizard, I get an error on the last step:

[image]

On error, it tells me that error log in inside a text file on the shown path. When I go to that path, there is no such file there.

I tried backup and then restore with a different name as well. But it gave similar results. I got error while restoring. But I couldn't find the error log file.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Where are you looking for the "error log file" from this operation?  And with the backup/restore approach, what was the error you got when you attempted to restore the database?

Comment: @ThomasStringer I looked for the file at the path as shown in the alert (attached screenshot)

Comment: @ThomasStringer that's the problem. I cannot find the error log files in any case. During the restore process, it showed me the error and asked me to look into error log file for more details. But the problem is that the error log file is not there on the said location.

Comment: Are you looking on your local machine, or on the server?  You should be looking on the server here the SQL Server instance actually lives.

Comment: I am looking on the server of course.

Comment: I am interested to see what the error message during your `RESTORE` operation is.  That should be rather specific.

Comment: In the RESTORE command have you renamed the files that are to be restored so that they are unique names?  Or are in a different path?

Comment: Thanks all for helping out. I have posted an alternative solution that worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to do it the other way. I created an empty DB and used import wizard to import all the data and the schemas. This worked without any error. But I still don't know why the Copy Wizard didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps of the SQL Agent Job:  detach the database, copy MDF and LDF files to the destination, then attach both source and destination to their respective instances.

It is possible that there was something preventing the detach.
You cannot detach a database that is replicated/published.
A database snapshot exists on the database.
It is being mirrored.
It is suspect.
It is a system database.

There could have been an issue with permissions copying the MDF and LDF files (not your login, but the SQLAgent service account login).

There could have been an issue with the attach.
A database created by a more recent version of SQL Server cannot be attached in earlier versions.

For the non-existent log file:  Ensure write permissions for the account that runs SQLAgent service on the folder where the log of the error would be written.